# Output of html_notebook in Viewer pane but not in Source pane

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

I was wondering whether it was possible to disable chunk output for RStudio's `html_notebook`s in the Source pane, so that output is only displayed in the Viewer pane (or in a separate Window, depending on your settings).

- I can manually close output of a single chunk in the Source pane by clicking on the "x" on the right of a code chunk, but this seems tedious.
- I can also control output with `include=FALSE`, but this obviously also affects the Viewer pane where I would like to have my output displayed.
- **Edit**: I would like to stick with the `html_notebook` format as updating changes with the notebook preview is much faster than knitting an `html_document`.

### Minimal Working Example (saved as `test.Rmd`):

````
---
title: "R Notebook Test"
output: html_notebook
---


HSome text here. 

```{r chunk1}
2+2
```

Some more text here.
````

The MWE results in the following output in the Source pane ...

[image: R source pane]

... and the following output in the Viewer pane:

[image: R viewer pane]

I am happy with the Viewer pane but do not want to see the output in the Source pane.

### Why am I asking this question?

I think the option of having output displayed in the Source pane is nice but since inline code chunks are not also rendered in the Source pane I prefer just having the output displayed once in the Viewer pane.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you need is **html_document**, (not **html_notebook**) where the source pane only has your code, but the viewer pane contains the processed chunks ?

Try changing `html_notebook` to `html_document` and see if that is what you need.   That will give you a clean source document and processed output in the window/viewer.

The html_notebook mode is specifically for dealing with

> " chunks that can be executed independently and interactively, with
>   output visible immediately beneath the input."

(see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I would like to stick with the notebook format as updating changes with the notebook preview is much faster than knitting an `html_document`.

Comment: The notebook format is all about having output visible immediately beneath your input - and yet  you say you don't want that ?   I'm a  bit confused as to what you want.

Comment: It is a nice feature, agreed. However, I see the primary advantage of the notebook in speed. When I am working on large reports, updating a notebook takes seconds, while re-knitting a regular document takes quite a while. I work with a lot of in-text chunks which are not rendered in the notebook's source but only in the viewer pane. I therefore prefer to just work with the viewer pane, as I otherwise had to switch forth and back between checking chunk output in the document source and in-text chunks in the viewer pane.